# How do I use MediaDevices.getUserMedia() to access camera in Ionic ios wkwebview?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, getusermedia

I want to use getUserMedia api to access camera in wkwebview, api working fine on android webview but ios is not, below is what i tried

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^6.0.0" />

<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
    <string>Used to take pictures</string>
</edit-config>
```

also manually add the string in Info.plist file
but it only works on safari, on ionic app it shows no error but no response nor asking for camera permission

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that api has issues in wkwebview. Check safari on IOS section [here](https://caniuse.com/stream). "Before iOS 14.3 getUserMedia returned no video input devices in UIWebView or WKWebView, but only directly in Safari."

Comment: Thanks for reply, I did a search and it seems a lot of people say it works well, is there any api similar getUserMedia that works well on WKWebview?

Comment: mostly test it in capacitor, i remember this problem happened from one year and it could be solved in any way, (i tried using different webviews than default that cordova use but didn't work, plus tried user media plugin but still didn't work as needed for streams as i wanted).. so when i put my pure js get user media code in capacitor, it worked perfectly.... so give it a test in capacitor,,,